# RichText doesn't work with bullets

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, rich-text-editor, richtext

See the simple application created below. I have a `RichTextEditor` and a `RichText` component. The idea is to display whatever typed in the RichTextEditor in the RichText component. Everything else (I think) works except for Bullets! The conversion works as if bullets don't exist!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application width="100%"
               height="100%"
               xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"             
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout />
    </s:layout>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import flashx.textLayout.conversion.TextConverter;          
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            protected function convert_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                richText.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(editor.htmlText, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>


    <mx:RichTextEditor id="editor" />

    <s:Button id="convert" click="convert_clickHandler(event)" />

    <s:RichText id="richText" />

</s:Application>
```

Any idea on how to make Bullets work with RichText ? Am I using the correct conversion method ? `TextConverter.importToFlow` ?

See the image below.

[image: Bullets]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List items are not a supported by [TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/conversion/TextConverter.html#TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT). You would need to create your own editor that supports the added TextFlow functionality. There is an example of one such editor in [Tour de' Flex](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-apps/flex/tourdeflex/web/), but it was written prior to list support in TLF 2. I'm not sure if it's been updated, but if not you will need to add in that functionality yourself.

Good luck!